# My first ETH mining rig RX 580 8GB

Tags: mining, mining-pools

I'm building my first eth mining rig. I considered the following hardware:

- GPU: 6 Sapphire nitro + RX 580 8GB
- MOBO: MSI Z270 TOMAHAWK LGA1151/ Intel Z270/ DDR4/ 2x CrssFX S3&U3.1/ M.2 ATX
- PSU: 1 1600W or 2 850W??
- RAM: FURY 4GB 2133 MHz DDR4
- CPU: INTEL PENTIUM G4400 Dual-Core 3.3GHz 8.0GT/S 3MB LGA 1151
- SSD: ethOS 16gb SSD (gpuShack)
- 6 USB risers

Are there any recommendations on this rig? Is there a better MOBO or CPU? Should I have a PSU of 1600W?

Please feel free to post any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome! This might get moderated out because you're asking for product recommentations.

Comment: Please also see and participate in https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/at-what-point-are-mining-questions-off-topic

Comment: @Lucas I have that mobo and I have problem that only detect 4 of 6 gpus, the problem is this: https://i.imgur.com/0PsI5wD.png, I'm trying to look for solutions

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want one 1600W PSU. You are just introducing needless issues with two. If you have to ask the question, it's definitely not a good idea. It will work, but it's not like an airplane where extra engines help. Bad things potentially happen when one fails and other is running.*

If you want to save on power, you are going to want a less powerful CPU, and have RAM at a lower clock speed. You also will want to undervolt a tad the GPUs. It gets real expensive fast, and these things add up when running 24/7.

Keeping temps under control is the big boy. You may find the same model of card being 10 degrees off all things being equal, and the way you cool can mean some card run hotter than others.

*Make sure your breakers and outlet can handle 1200W pull. Using two GPUs could be advised in some cases where this is an issue.